# 2 x 2 lines equation on a single line separated by a text in the middle

Tags: equations, subequations

How to write 2 x 2 rows equation on a single line separated by a text in the middle of the form:

[image]

The picture example is the result that I want to reproduce and can't (which I found in a textbook)

An imperfect try to reproduce the output would be:

```
\begin{flalign*}
a_n &= c_n + c_{-n} && && c_n &= \frac{1}{2} (a_n - ib_n)\\
&& \text{or} && \\
b_n &= i(c_n - c_{-n}) && && c{_n} &= \frac{1}{2} (a_n + ib_n)
\end{flalign*}
```

with the following rendering:

[image]

However:

- the `or` separating the two sides takes an entire row (instead of sitting on the half row between the 2 row equations)
- the 2 row equation of the right is put way to far on the right

Comment: I added a MWE @CarLaTeX

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Mico advised in the comments that the spacing is not good, I edited my answer. Thanks Mico!

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\[
    \begin{array}{rcl}
        a_n & = & c_n+c_{-n}\\[1ex]
        b_n & = & i(c_n-c_{-n})
    \end{array} \qquad \text{or} \qquad
    \begin{array}{rcl}
        c_n & = & \frac{1}{2}(a_n-ib_n)\\[1ex]
        c_{-n}&=& \frac{1}{2}(a_n+ib_n)
    \end{array}.
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: If there is only one line, what is the purpose of using `align` here?

Comment: The horizontal spacing around the four `=` symbols is too loose with this solution.

Comment: @ArtificialStupidity Actually I tried `\begin{align*} Hello & \text{or} & Hello \end{align*}` at first. But it failed. I changed to this one and forget changing `\begin\end{align*}` to something like `\[\]`. Thanks for your feedback!

Comment: @Mico You know, one can always change the spacing between lines by `\\[1ex]`, for example. Thanks for your feedback! I will edit my answer now.

Comment: Oh, sorry @Mico I didn't scroll down to see your answer first :| so my answer is just exactly the same :|

Comment: My earlier comment was meant to address the horizontal spacing around the `=` symbols. The vertical distance between the rows is a separate matter.

Comment: @Mico Ah, I see. Of course it's not good, but you can see the horizontal spacing around the `=` in the question is the same.

Comment: @DũngVũ - Yeah, it very much looks like the OP copied a typographically questionable example form his/her textbook, doesn't it?

Comment: @Mico Yes, I think so.

Answer (score 6):

```
\documentclass[preview,border=12pt,varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\[
    \begin{aligned}
        a_n &= c_n + c_{-n}\\
        b_n &= i(c_n - c_{-n})
    \end{aligned}
    \qquad
    \text{or}
    \qquad
    \begin{aligned}
        c_n         &= \frac{a_n-ib_n}{2}\\
    c_{-n}  &= \frac{a_n+ib_n}{2}
    \end{aligned}
\]
Is it what you are looking for?
\end{document}
```

[image]

## My proposal

```
\documentclass[preview,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[a6paper,landscape,margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
I prefer the following style because it is clearer what we are grouping, how about you?
\[
    \left\{
        \begin{aligned}
        a_n &= c_n + c_{-n}\\
        b_n &= i(c_n - c_{-n})
    \end{aligned}\right.
    \qquad
    \text{or}
    \qquad
        \left\{
    \begin{aligned}
        c_n &= \tfrac12(a_n-ib_n)\\
    c_{-n}  &= \tfrac12(a_n+ib_n)
    \end{aligned}\right.
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Here's a version of [@DüngVü's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/460566/5001) that applies the correct amount of whitespace around the four `=` symbols.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array} % for "\newcolumntype" macro
\newcolumntype{C}{>{{}}c<{{}}}
\begin{document}
\[
\setlength\arraycolsep{0pt}
    \begin{array}{rCl}
        a_n & = & c_n+c_{-n}    \\[1ex]
        b_n & = & i(c_n-c_{-n})
    \end{array} 
    \qquad \mbox{or} \qquad
    \begin{array}{rCl}
        c_n   & = & \frac{1}{2}(a_n-ib_n) \\[1ex]
        c_{-n}& = & \frac{1}{2}(a_n+ib_n)
    \end{array}
\]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

I wouldn't use `flalign*` that spreads out the equations too much.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,mathtools}

\begin{document}

\begin{flalign*}
a_n &= c_n + c_{-n} & c_n &= \frac{1}{2} (a_n - ib_n)\\
\shortintertext{\centering or}
b_n &= i(c_n - c_{-n}) & c{_n} &= \frac{1}{2} (a_n + ib_n)
\end{flalign*}

\begin{alignat*}{2}
a_n &= c_n + c_{-n} &\hspace{5em} c_n &= \frac{1}{2} (a_n - ib_n)\\
\shortintertext{\centering or}
b_n &= i(c_n - c_{-n}) & c{_n} &= \frac{1}{2} (a_n + ib_n)
\end{alignat*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

On the other hand, it is not really clear what “or” refers to; I'd suggest placing “or” at the left margin. Just remove `\centering` from the second example to get

[image]

Comment: `{_n}` must be corrected as `{-n}`.